# Replace bokeh object inside div on-click

Tags: html, jquery, bokeh

I'm able to get the bokeh object to render properly inside a div on the webpage. The bokeh object is returned via Flask and is generated based on a user-click. However, my problem is that on every user-click, the new bokeh object that is produced, gets appended to the div.

I've read about the .html() way of replacing content, and I've also read about document.getElementById, but I'm not sure how to replace my div content and avoid the append. Any help is appreciated.

The relevant snippet from my index.html

```
rows.forEach(row => {

    row.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var pic = <<my_url>> + ($(row).attr("data-href"));
        $.ajax({
            data : {},
            dataType: "json",
            type : 'GET',
            url : <<my flask app path>>
        })
        .then(function(response) {return response;})
        .then(function(item) {
            Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item);
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emptying the contents of the div on-click is the approach I took to resolve my situation. i.e.,

```
$(div).empty();
```